# Distorcimento do layout no Bluestack

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, layout-responsivo

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="false">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Cadastrar ..."
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="68dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/imgViewContactImage"
        android:src="@drawable/camera"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="81dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Escolher Foto"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txtNome"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:shadowColor="#ffbfbfbf"
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:hint="Nome do Tema"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/mic"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtNome"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="75dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Escolher Som"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgViewContactImage"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:textColor="#ff000000" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cadastrar"
        android:id="@+id/btnCadTema"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Voltar"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgViewContactImage"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gravar Som"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:textColor="#ff000000" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/mic"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Eu uso a minha aplicação do formato do Nexus 10 no modo Landscape no Android Studio, só que quando eu uso a máquina virtual do Bluestacks para rodar a minha aplicação ela aparece toda distorcida, não do jeito que eu montei no layout.[image: Na Maquina Virtual Bluestack]

[image: Na aplicação do Android Studio]

Eu testei no Eclipse, ele não tem distorção, somente a do Android Studio

Comment: Poderias adicionar o código relevante à tua pergunta?

Comment: Não sei se era isso o que dizia, mas postei o código da tela.
O que está dando problema é que aparece todo distorcido quando eu uso o Android Studio na maquina virtual, mas somente na maquina virtual que distorci tudo

Comment: @GabrielSantanaBonatto você terá que criar suponho eu, uma tela em Portrait e outra em Landscape, isso no Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O único jeito que eu achei para este problema foi trocar o formato para resolução menor de tela, caso alguém saiba de alguma outra solução, serei muito grato :)